# How to use {% for in %} symfony?

Tags: css, symfony, templates, view, controller

My problem that when i use the loop , the data inside don't show up , 
this is the code here im using the loop even " mes boutiques " dont show,  [, only "shirts & tops" show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goso4.png)

[and this function where im calling this template in the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkdQW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your function affichDQL() must have a problem, you should test the result in your controller with dump($enseignes); to see if you haves results. You can add an check in your twig too with {% dump(enseignes) %}

Comment: thanks everyone , the problem was in afficheDQL(), yes , there wasn't any data to return!

Answer (score 0):

Your template looks ok. The problem probably is in the repository method that probably return the DQL: a string representing the  query in Doctrine.

I suspect you have a method like this in your entity method:

```
// retrieve the DQL string of what was defined in QueryBuilder
$dql = $qb->getDql();
```

So you need to replace with something like this:

```
// retrieve the associated Query object with the processed DQL
$query = $qb->getQuery();

// Execute Query
$result = $query->getResult();

return $result;
```

Hope this help